# Bootsrap 4 targetting navbar a tags and backround of whole navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I dont understand why I have to make id's for everything when there are classes for these boostrap 4 classes. I try accessing them using `.navbar` but it doesnt do anything.
here is my whole code in HTML

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <img id="logoName" class="navbar-brand mx-auto" src="images/logo2.png">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBar" aria-controls="navBar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-right">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Deals</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Online Ordering</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How do I accesss navbar to change the background or "a"?

Comment: What exactly are you accessing, the `<a>` elements? And how do you access them?

Comment: @Drearo What is your question?

Comment: @CarlBinalla Yes, I can't access anything without making an ID. for example if I want to access the whole navbar, I can't simply use .navbar and do { background:red;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just do

```
.navbar{background:red;}
```

and this works fine. Try removing the bg-light class from your HTML as this is telling the background to be light, or you can add !important to you CSS class

```
.navbar{background:red !important}
```

which will force the colour change, but I wouldn't recommend this way

Comment: I had to remove the bg-light. Thank you.